# Best practice to load external feed by curl?

Tags: curl, zend-framework2

I have a task to write application which will consume external feed.
The feed is private and will return vehicle information from 3rd party in xml format.
I've used it before using curl.

1. What would be the best Zend Framework 2 practice to build the application - in terms how to organise Controllers/Actions/Services or so?
2. Is there any CURL implementation in ZF2 which I can use?

Comment: the curl adapter is prob what your looking for http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.http.client.adapters.html#the-curl-adapter. Also you might just want to write a factory/service retrieving the feed and alter it in the controller then just pass it to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zend already provide the default Feed Reader/Writer module, Why not just using    Zend\Feed\Reader\Reader   http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.feed.reader.html .

If you are keen to user Curl, Then you also have choice of extensive Client Adapters  http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.http.client.adapters.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't use Feed Reader as the source is not fully compatible with standards. I will use HTTP Client adapter instead. Also I figured how to make it correctly structured.